# CDT Plugin Error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: plugins, view, eclipse-cdt

Made a plugin using Eclipse Java (in Windows).
Tested and Exported the plugin.

Imported the plugin in Eclipse CDT (in Linux).

Get the following exception:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myUI cannot be found by myJar_1.0.0.201708011131

Any idea as to why? I have been researching this for some time and have tried many many "solutions".

Please advise.

Comment: Try unzipping the jar to ensure that it contains the class files you expect.

Comment: For some reason, I could not get the referenced class (which is a referneced JAR) to export. I did some research and tried different solutions that have been posted by others.